# Is it possible to use custom attributes as criteria in my query

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I'm wondering, is it possible to use a custom attribute in sails to query certain records?
Maybe my example below will explain it better.

models/User.js

```
 attributes: { first_name: 'string', last_name: 'string' }
```

models/ModelA.js

```
 attributes: {
  user: {model: 'User'},
  studentName: function(){ return this.user.first_name + " " this.user.last_name },
  ....
 }
```

My Query

```
ModelA.find({studentName: {contains: searchKeyword }}).populate('user').then(console.log);
```

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 0):

No, Waterline won't evaluate an instance method during a query.  It also wouldn't have access to the populated model at the time that the criteria would be evaluated; i.e. `this.user` would be null.  You'll need to perform the `find` without the `studentName` attribute, and then filter the result yourself:

```
ModelA.find().populate('user').exec(function(err, models) {

    models = _.where(models, function(model) {
        return model.studentName().match(searchKeyword);
    }

});
```

If this is a real example, it may be better to search **User** models instead, populating  **ModelA**:

```
User.find(
    {or: [
        {firstName: {contains: searchKeyword}}, 
        {lastName: {contains: searchKeyword}}
    ]}
).populate('modela').exec(...)
```